# Registration of user through servlet error

Tags: mysql, jsp, authentication

I made a JSP page with a create user form, a servlet and my web.xml file. When I hit the submit button nothing happens. I don't get an error or something, just nothing happens. Can anyone see what it is I do wrong?

Best Regards
Mads

JSP:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="Registration" method="POST">
        Firstname:  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="">
        Lastname:   <input type="password" name="lastname" value="">
                    <input type="button" value="submit"></input>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Servlet:

```
package myservlets;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
public class Registration extends HttpServlet{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException{
        super.init(config);
    }
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) 
        throws ServletException, IOException{

        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/logindatabase";
        Connection connection=null;
        ResultSet rs;
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();

        String fname = req.getParameter("firstname");
        String sname = req.getParameter("lastname");

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", ""); 
            String sql = "INSERT INTO login VALUES (?,?)";
            PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, fname);
            pst.setString(2, sname);

            int numRowsChanged = pst.executeUpdate();
            out.println(" Welcome : ");
            out.println(" '"+fname+"'");
            pst.close();
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e){

            out.println("Couldn't load database driver: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            out.println("SQLException caught: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            out.println(e);
        }
        finally {

        try {
            if (connection != null) connection.close();
        }
            catch (SQLException ignored){
                out.println(ignored);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <description>
        User Registration and Login Example.
    </description>
    <display-name>User Registration and Login Example</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Registration</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>myservlets.Registration</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Registration</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Registration</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are **not submitting form.**

```
<input type="button" value="submit"></input>
```

This does not submit form. It is simple button.

Change to

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

#### See also

- http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input

Comment: Ah of course thanks a lot for that. Now i get the message "Welcome Mads". But when I update my database, I do not get any in data in my columns fname and sname. Do you know why that could be?

Comment: Ops now it came. I have forgotten that I have out commented :
ResultSet rs; and int numRowsChanged = pst.executeUpdate();
Thanks a lot for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

The correct code is:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"
    pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="Registration" method="POST">
        Firstname:  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="">
        Lastname:   <input type="password" name="lastname" value="">
                    <input type="submit" value="submit"></input>
    </form>

</body>
</html>

package myservlets;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
public class Registration extends HttpServlet{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException{
        super.init(config);
    }
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) 
        throws ServletException, IOException{

        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/logindatabase";
        Connection connection=null;
        ResultSet rs;
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();

        String fname = req.getParameter("firstname");
        String sname = req.getParameter("lastname");

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", ""); 
            String sql = "INSERT INTO login VALUES (?,?)";
            PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, fname);
            pst.setString(2, sname);

            int numRowsChanged = pst.executeUpdate();
            out.println(" Welcome : ");
            out.println(" '"+fname+"'");
            pst.close();
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e){

            out.println("Couldn't load database driver: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            out.println("SQLException caught: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            out.println(e);
        }
        finally {

        try {
            if (connection != null) connection.close();
        }
            catch (SQLException ignored){
                out.println(ignored);
            }
        }
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <description>
        User Registration and Login Example.
    </description>
    <display-name>User Registration and Login Example</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Registration</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>myservlets.Registration</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Registration</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Registration</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Hope someone can use it for something.
Best Regards 
Mads

Answer (score 0):

He's (@Aniket Kulkarni) telling right. But your going right way for almost you got it. These are several ways you can submit your forms. Just look at my model are following as:

```
<input type="button">
```

The button INPUT tag gives a lot of the same options as the image INPUT tag, but looks more like the standard submit type. It requires JavaScript to activate.

```
<button></button>
```

The BUTTON tag is a more versatile type of button than the INPUT tag. This tag requires Javacript to activate.

```
<command type="command">
```

The COMMAND element is new in HTML5, and it provides a way to activate scripts and forms with associated actions. It is activated with JavaScript.

&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&

**The INPUT Element**

The INPUT element is the most common way to submit a form, all you do is choose a type (button, image, or submit) and if necessary add some scripting to submit to the form action.

The  element can be written just like that. But if you do, you will have different results in different browsers. Most browsers make a button that says “Submit,” but Firefox makes a button that says “Submit Query.” To change what the button says, you should add a value attribute:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit Form">
```

The  element is written like that, but if you leave off all other attributes, all that will display in browsers is an empty gray button. To add text to the button, use the value attribute. But this button won't submit the form unless you use JavaScript.

```
<input type="button" value="Submit Form" onclick="submit();">
```

The  is similar to the button type, which needs a script to submit the form. Except that instead of a text value, you need to add an image source URL.

```
<input type="image" onclick="submit();" src="submit.gif">
```

&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&

**The BUTTON Element**

The BUTTON element requires both an opening tag  and a closing tag  When you use it, any content you enclose inside the tag will be enclosed in a button. Then you activate the button with a script.

```
<button onclick="submit();">Submit Form</button>
```

You can include images in your button or combine images and text to create a more interesting button.

```
<button onclick="submit();"><img src="submit.gif" />Submit Form</button>
```

&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&

**The COMMAND Element**

The COMMAND element is new with HTML5. It does not require a FORM to be used, but it can act as a submit button for a form. This element allows you to create more interactive pages without requiring forms unless you really need forms. If you want the command to say something, you write the information in a label attribute.

```
<command type="command" onclick="submit();" label="Submit Form">
```

If you want your command to be represented by an image, you use the icon attribute.

```
<command type="command" onclick="submit();" icon="submit.gif">
```

&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&

*I think I've clear your doubt for all submit types. But, now you just follow this input element and run your program.*

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit Form" or value="Submit">
```