# How to make submit and save button work on jsp page?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, jsp

I am creating a form..i want my form to have two buttons one for "submit" and the other for "Save as draft".when I click on submit the data has to be submitted and when I click on save it should show the filled form on another page.I know how to submit and save independently but how do I make them work in the same form.my code is as follows

```
<form method="post" action="submitpage.jsp" >//I want here in action to change according to the button clicked
<table border="2" >
<tr>
<td>Field 1</td>
<td><input  type="text" style=" width: 150px; height: 15px" value="" name="Field1"  id="F1"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Field 2</td>
<td><input  type="text" style=" width: 150px; height: 15px" value="" name="Field2"  id="F2" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Field 3</td>
<td><input  type="text" style=" width: 150px; height: 15px" value="" name="Field3"  id="F3" /></td>
</tr>
<td>Field 4</td>
<td><input  type="text" style=" width: 150px; height: 15px" value="" name="Field4"  id="F4" /></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return js_file_for_validation()" autofocus="autofocus"/></td>
<td><input type="button" value="Save as draft" /></td>
</tr>
</table></form>

</form>
```

P.s:-I AM USING JAVASCRIPT FOR VALIDATING SUBMIT!!!!
IS there anything that I have to write in js file ??? Guidance will be helpful!!

Thanks in adv!!

Comment: Use an if statement,isnt that obvious?when u press submit do this or else once u press save do something else...do this in ur js.U could use 2 submits instead of one submit and one button.

Comment: You cant use a button to send send data to another page,you will have to use a submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write another javascript function and map it to the onclick event of save button

```
<td><input type="button" onclick="return saveForm();" value="Save as draft" /></td>
```

And the java script method as ,

**Java script**

```
function saveForm(){
document.form[0].submit;
}
```

In your servlet get the attributes and show your filled form.

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return js_file_for_validation()" autofocus="autofocus"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Save as draft" /></td>
```

At servlet.java

```
if (request.getParameter("submit") != null) {
 //add values to the database  

} else if (request.getParameter("submit1") != null) {
      //save as draft button is clicked
}
```

Comment: If I give submit its not validating the form.if I give as button its not directing to the page for the First Button!!Thnks for the input!!

Comment: @Vishnu you havent given any action to the button.But that wont help as you wont be able to recieve the parameters on the draft page without a form

Comment: by the way the name of the first submit is `submit` not `submit1`...that was a typo mistake by me..also instead of onclick,say onsubmit..

Comment: @Vishnu you need to reply so we can help you solve and v can close this question.

Answer (score 0):

**The save operation is following as:**

**this servlet page:**

```
    public class UserController extends HttpServlet 
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private static String DEP_EDIT="/editdepartment.jsp";
    //other details
    }

    protected void dotGet(HttpServletRequest request,
      HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
  if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("depedit"))
    {
        forward=DEP_EDIT;
        int dep_Id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("dep_Id"));
        User user=dao.getUserById(dep_Id);
        request.setAttribute("user", user);
    }  //other operation
    }
```

**this is save.jsp page:**

```
  <form method="post" action='UserController?action=depedit' >

            Department ID : <input type="text" name="dep_id"
                value="<c:out value="${user.dep_id}" />" /> <br />
            Employee Department: <input type="text" name="depName" 
                value="<c:out value="${user.depName}"/>"/><br/>

            <input type="submit" value="save"/>
```

**And the submit is same as save, just look at that code and following links.**

```
   public class UserController extends HttpServlet 
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private static String DEP_LIST="/departmentlist.jsp";
    //other details
    }

    protected void dotGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
       HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("departmentlist"))
    {
        forward=DEP_LIST;
        request.setAttribute("users", dao.getAll());
    }
}
```

**this is submit.jsp page:**

```
 <form method="post" action='UserController?action=depedit' >

            Department ID : <input type="text" name="dep_id"
                value="<c:out value="${user.dep_id}" />" /> <br />
            Employee Department: <input type="text" name="depName" 
                value="<c:out value="${user.depName}"/>"/><br/>

            <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
```

click this link to get the all type of submit buttons and full details

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21927496/3242978